# Adding slider to demo application

Tags: javascript, nativescript

I am trying to add a slider to one of the demo applications. I added a slider to the home-fragment.xml by adding

```
<Slider value="{{ slider }}" horizontalAlignment="center" width="80%"/>
```

Now I want to be able to edit and read data from this slider from my viewmodel. According to [the slider documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/ui/slider) I need to import the slider and then create it. My code now looks like this:

```
import { Slider } from "tns-core-modules/ui/slider";

const observableModule = require("data/observable");
const slider = new Slider();

function HomeViewModel() {
    const viewModel = observableModule.fromObject({

    });
    slider.value = 0;

    return viewModel;
}

module.exports = HomeViewModel;
```

Visual Studio Code does not show any errors but once I launch the app I get the following error:

```
An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.nativescript.app/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}: com.tns.NativeScriptException: 
Calling js method onCreate failed

Error: Building UI from XML. @file:///app/tabs/tabs-page.xml:30:13
 > Unexpected token import
File: "file:///data/data/org.nativescript.app/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder/builder.js, line: 208, column: 20
```

I am new to Nativescript and probably made a mistake in the architecture or setup. Can somebody help me out by showing me what goes wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it could be a couple of things, but one thing is certain: you don't need to import that Slider component to set its value. You can simply bind to a property (`slider = 20;`).

The easiest way to start with NativeScript, and to learn how those UI widgets work, is by using the Playground. I've created a little project with a Slider for you to show how it works in "plain" NativeScript with TypeScript: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=I7SGei

Comment: Thank you for the help! I wanted to actively listen to the changed values but couldn't get this to work. Any chance you can help me with my [follow up question? :)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49800467/nativescript-log-slider-value-on-update)