# Nativescript log slider value on update

Tags: javascript, nativescript

I am new to Nativescript. Yesterday I asked how to create a slider and read those values. This question was answered however now I want to log those values once the value of the slider has been updated.

I made a sample project that prints the value once I press a button. Now I want to print the value each time the value of the slider changes. I looked at the [slider documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/ui/slider) and the [propertyChange event](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/events#propertychange-event) documentation but can't get this to work.

Here is the link to the playground I am trying this in: [Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=jpFnU7&v=3)

Can anybody tell me how I'd properly bind my slider to the observable and how I'd capture the event that fires once the value updates?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could attach to the `valueChange` listener via code-behind.

```
exports.onSliderLoaded = function (args) {
  const slider = args.object;

  slider.on("valueChange", (args) => { 
    console.log(args.value);
  })
}
```

Where `onSliderLoaded` is used via the `loaded` event for your slider

```
<Slider value="{{ slider }}" loaded="onSliderLoaded" />
```

Full Playground demo demonstrating the above can be found [here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=jpFnU7&v=4)

Comment: For added clarity, is there a way to bind this Slider event via XML? Or is it only possible to bind this specific event via code?

Comment: Depending on your coding choice - In NativeScript Core (XML + TS or JS) you can do it only via code-behind and not via the XML. In an Angular based app, you could use the Angular syntax and add the `Change` keyword in your HTML (as done here https://github.com/NickIliev/nativescript-ng-cosmos/blob/b13fe38ebb87f6b472335687b0a4e6b246b1d80d/app/pages/rovers/pickers/pickers.component.html#L7).